# Kotlin 1.3.0 mapping interface implementation to Java class extension at compile time

Tags: android, kotlin

Since updating to Kotlin 1.3.0, a couple of my classes like the one below

```
class BrokenClass : Parcelable, Serializable {
    var id: Int? = null
    ...
}
```

are causing compile time errors like

```
error: no interface expected here 
public final class AccessCode extends android.os.Parcelable implements java.io.Serializable {
```

So the Kotlin processor is treating the first interface as a class and putting it in extends instead of implements.

Comment: Adding `Any` to the beginning of the extends list like this

    class BrokenClass : Any, Parcelable, Serializable

fixes the problem but shouldn't be necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-27506
Target fix is Kotlin 1.3.30

In the mean time you can work around this by explicitly extending from Any:

```
class BrokenClass : Any(), Parcelable, Serializable {
    var id: Int? = null
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add @Parcelize annotation at the beginning.

https://proandroiddev.com/parcelable-in-kotlin-here-comes-parcelize-b998d5a5fcac

Comment: I am moving to using @Parcelize but the class in question does implement all of the necessities from Parcelable. Additionally, changing the order  so Serializable first gives me the same problem.